# Weird nullpointer exception

Tags: java, android

I have this method in my superclass, which extends activity:

```
protected boolean isStopAvailable(BusStop stop) {
    if (stop == null) {
        stop = new BusStop();
    } else if (stop.getName().length() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I call it in my subclass `isStopAvailable(object)`; How is it even possible to get a null pointer exception while using a method from the object *after* I've initiated the object?

Comment: If I may ask - which city? London?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stop.getName()` returns `null`

```
else if (stop.getName() != null && stop.getName().length() > 0)
```

should solve it

Comment: @user1163392, We've all been there :)

Answer (score 3):

If `getName()` returns null, you will get a NPE. You are trying to do a length function on a null object, hence this exception. You should add another `else if` check:

```
...
else if (stop.getName() == null) {
    // do something
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

stop.getName() is  returning null ,that is why you are getting [NPE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that the `name` field in `stop` is null. Your first check is to see if the object is null, not the fields inside of it. Thus, if `stop.getName()` returns null, you get an NPE when attempting to invoke the length

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that the NPE is thrown in this line: `else if (stop.getName().length() > 0)`
Thats possible because you've checked if the object `BusStop` is `null` but you didn't checked if `stop.getName()` could be `null`.

Do something like that:

```
else if (stop.getName() == null) {
   // set stop.setName()
}
```

Hope this helped, Have Fun!